# Can't put view overlaping Android VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview

Why I can't put a view with black background overlaping a VideoView? I can set any bakcground color to my view and this color overlaps correctly the VideoView, but when I set the background color as black, the view's background turns into gray color. This is my code

```
       <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <VideoView
                android:id="@+id/videoView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/FileNotFound"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Video not found"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="22dp"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/black"/>

        </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the view is not overlapping the VideoView completely. Set the width of View to match_parent as follows:

```
 <View
     android:layout_width="match_parent" <!--here-->
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@color/black"/>
```

Comment: When I put width as match_parent I'm getting the same result. Only with black color, other colors works fine.

Comment: can you try using "#000000" instead of "@color/black"  ?

Comment: Yes, but I got the same, it's seems like the view is getting transparency automatically.

Comment: can you post the whole layout? it is working correctly when i try it.